# How often imgur changed URL on the pictures?

Tags: imgur

I'm going to make the site gallery. Pictures will be posted on imgur. I need to know imgur will change imgs url or not?

And how long images are stored on this service?

Comment: Did you look here? https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us

Comment: @OlaEkdahl, yes, but no found answer